# Is `String` truly a reference type in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
struct User {
    username: String,
    email: String,
    sign_in_count: u64,
    active: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let mut user = User {
        username: String::from("Paulx"),
        email: String::from("paulx@gmail.io"),
        sign_in_count: 0,
        active: true,
    };

    let name = user.username;
    user.username = String::from("Alix");

    println!("{}", name);
}
```

You will see that the `username` is copied from user the the variable `name`. The variable `name` is not scalar type, why can it make this copy?

Comment: What do you mean by "and the variable name wasn't changed as user.username."?

Comment: I made a misunderstand here. I thought the variable 'name' and user.username are refer to same heap block same time. It actually move the value from user.username to name.

Comment: The only time when multiple variables refer to the same heap block is when you use `Rc`/`Arc`. Otherwise, everytime you assign something, you either move or copy it, depending on whether the `Copy` trait is implemented, which for `String`, it isn't.

Comment: What you maybe intended was to use `let name = &user.username`, e.g. a reference. But that would prevent `user.username = String::from("Alix")` from happening, because you cannot modify a value while it is borrowed. That's one of the basic axioms of the rust borrow checker.

Comment: yah, Rust has strict check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here.

You did not **copy** the `user.username`, you **moved it out**.

Until you assign a new `user.username`, the entry `user.username` is **invalid**.

See here:

```
struct User {
    username: String,
}

fn main() {
    let mut user = User {
        username: String::from("Paulx"),
    };

    let name = user.username;

    // Fails to compile!
    println!("{}", user.username);

    user.username = String::from("Alix");

    // Works again.
    println!("{}", user.username);

    println!("{}", name);
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `user.username`
  --> src/main.rs:13:20
   |
10 |     let name = user.username;
   |                ------------- value moved here
...
13 |     println!("{}", user.username);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `user.username` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::format_args_nl` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Comment: This answer my question well. I often mixed up the reference in rust with that in other language.